# Aggregate data from list of Requests in a crawler

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Perhaps I am missing something simple, so I *hope* this is an easy question.  I am using Scrapy to parse a directory listing and then pull down each appropriate web page (actually a text file) and parse it out using Python.

Each page has a set of data I am interested in, and I update a global dictionary each time I encounter such an item in each page.

What I would *like* to do is simply print out an aggregate summary when all Request calls are complete, however after the `yield` command nothing runs.  I am assuming because `yield` is actually returning a generator and bailing out.

I'd like to avoid writing a file for each `Request` object if possible...I'd rather keep it self contained within this Python script.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
 from scrapy.http import Request

 slain = {}

 class GameSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "game"
   allowed_domains = ["example.org"]
   start_urls = [
     "http://example.org/users/deaths/"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
     links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
     for link in links:
       if 'txt' in link:
         l = self.start_urls[0] + link
         yield Request(l, callback=self.parse_following, dont_filter=True)

 # Ideally print out the aggregate after all Requests are satisfied    
 #    print "-----"
 #    for k,v in slain.iteritems():
 #      print "Slain by %s: %d" % (k,v)
 #    print "-----"

   def parse_following(self, response):
     parsed_resp = response.body.rstrip().split('\n')
     for line in parsed_resp:
       if "Slain" in line:
         broken = line.split()
         slain_by = broken[3]

         if (slain_by in slain):
           slain[slain_by] += 1
         else:
           slain[slain_by] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed(reason) function, it is called when the spider finishes.

```
def closed(self, reason):
    for k,v in self.slain.iteritems():
        print "Slain by %s: %d" % (k,v)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for a callback function but for some reason couldn't find this one.